# Pearson Correlation "Stratified" by Categorical Variable

Tags: r

I am very new to R.

I am interested in calculating Pearson Correlations for my data. I have successfully figured out how to calculate the correlation of two continuous variables within my data set, x and y; however, I am hoping to "stratify" the correlations by a third, categorical variable: state. I would like to be able to say "the correlation co-efficient/p-value of x and y is [Result] in [State]."

I have tried the group_by method, located in the dplyr package, housed within the cor.test (shown below). I am in need of both the coefficients and the p-values, so I have been trying to use the cor.test method. I have also tried using a matrix method, but was unsuccessful that way as well.

```
Data<-read.csv("PATHWAYNAME")
  library(dplyr)
  CCor<-cor.test(Data$x, Data$y,
          method=c("pearson"), group_by(State))
  CCor
```

I am able to run each set of values for each state individually to get the coefficients and p-values; however, I am certain that there is a more efficient way to complete this task. My data is large enough that it will be beyond tedious to run them individually.

Thank you in advance for your help!

**UPDATE:**
Using this as a sample data set that is extremely truncated, but similarly represents the variables in my own, I would like to know if the average income correlates with the number of visits in each state listed; that is, does the average income have a positive or negative correlation with the number of visits in the state of Alabama?

```
>State  NumVis  AvgIncome
>IN       45        60000
>AL       100       56000
>AK       45        80000
>ME       89        54000
>NC       120       100000
>SC       356       43000
>ND       100       25000
>SD       63        20000
>MN       54        46000
>ID       85        55000
```

When running this data using the code indicated below, my outcome is this:

```
 CorrDat<-read.csv("File")
     CorrDat %>%
       group_by(State) %>%
        do(tidy(cor.test(CorrDat$NumVis, CorrDat$Income, method="pearson")))
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M9Tf.png)

Would you be able to help clarify what it is that I am doing incorrectly with this code or if I need to use an alternative method to accomplish this task?

Comment: Effectively, I'm looking for the equivalent of the Class Statement in SAS, but for R.

Comment: Its easier to help you if you provide a proper [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the desired output for that input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways this can be accomplished in R. `dplyr` or more generally `tidyverse` are a popular group of tools that are able to achieve the desired result. The key difference in these tools is the pipe `%>%` which provides a means to write code from left to right instead of from the inside out (or to make a bunch of intermediary objects in the environment). Although the pipe can be used with base R its popularity came with `dplyr`.

Here are several examples on mtcars data set. The key functions are `do` and `map` which are quite versatile. I suggest running `?do` and `?map`.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(cor = cor(mpg, disp))
#output
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl correlation
  <dbl>       <dbl>
1     4  -0.8052361
2     6   0.1030827
3     8  -0.5197670
```

another way is:

```
mtcars  %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(cor = cor(.$mpg, .$disp)) %>%
  unnest()
```

or for more variables:

```
mtcars  %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(cor = as.data.frame(cor(.[,-2]) )) %>%
  unnest()
```

an example with cor.test:

```
library(broom)

mtcars  %>% 
  group_by(cyl)  %>% 
  do(tidy(cor.test(.$mpg, .$disp))) 
#output
    cyl   estimate  statistic     p.value parameter   conf.low   conf.high                               method alternative
  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>     <int>      <dbl>       <dbl>                               <fctr>      <fctr>
1     4 -0.8052361 -4.0740206 0.002782827         9 -0.9474526 -0.39724826 Pearson's product-moment correlation   two.sided
2     6  0.1030827  0.2317344 0.825929685         5 -0.7046776  0.79446840 Pearson's product-moment correlation   two.sided
3     8 -0.5197670 -2.1075838 0.056774876        12 -0.8232990  0.01492976 Pearson's product-moment correlation   two.sided
```

and yet another way using purrr::map:

```
mtcars  %>% 
  split(.$cyl)  %>% 
  map(~cor.test(.x$mpg, .x$disp))
```

which gives a list, which can be manipulated with the same or another map function:

```
mtcars  %>% 
  split(.$cyl)  %>% 
  map(~cor.test(.x$mpg, .x$disp)) %>%
  map_dbl("p.value")
#output:
          4           6           8 
0.002782827 0.825929685 0.056774876
```

to extract the coefficients:

```
mtcars  %>% 
  split(.$cyl)  %>% 
  map(~cor.test(.x$mpg, .x$disp)) %>%
  map(~data.frame(cor = .x$estimate, p = .x$p.value)) #check also `map_dfr` and `map_dfc`

#output
$`4`
           cor           p
cor -0.8052361 0.002782827

$`6`
          cor         p
cor 0.1030827 0.8259297

$`8`
          cor          p
cor -0.519767 0.05677488
```

UPDATE: answer to the updated question:

The problem is how you specify the `do` call. This is correct:

```
df %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  do(tidy(cor.test(.$NumVis, .$AvgIncome, method="pearson")))
```

where the `.` represents the data passed by the previous pipe. In the example posted this results in:

```
Error in cor.test.default(.$NumVis, .$AvgIncome, method = "pearson") : 
not enough finite observations
```

which is reasonable considering only 1 observation per group is suplied

what you did is:

```
CorrDat<-read.csv("File")
     CorrDat %>%
       group_by(State) %>%
        do(tidy(cor.test(CorrDat$NumVis, CorrDat$Income, method="pearson")))
```

passing the whole CorrDat set to the `do` function so it performed the same operation as many times as there are groups.

The `%>%` pipe assumes the data passed will be used as the first argument in the following function, if it should not the data can be refereed to as `.`. You can perform operations like `.$column` or `.[,2]` etc.

Comment: @user9165024  updated the post. The error was spotted and explained. If anything is unclear please let me know. Usually when clarification is achieved the comments can be deleted. I deleted mine.

Comment: Would you be able to further clarify the first error you received? I am getting that error when I run my data:  Error in cor.test.default(.$NumVis, .$AvgIncome, method = "pearson") : 
not enough finite observations. I made the alterations to the code as you suggested! Thank you for your thorough explanation!

Comment: @user9165024 If any of the groups has 2 or less observations this error will occur. Try: `cor.test(1:2, rnorm(2))` and `cor.test(1:3, rnorm(3))`. A strait line can be defined by two points so there is no point calculating correlation, It will be 1. Remove groups that have less than 3 observations and run the code again.

Answer (score 0):

With base r, you could use [`by`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/by.html).

E.g., replicating one of the examples in missuse's post:

```
do.call(rbind,
        by(mtcars, mtcars$cyl, FUN = function(x) cor.test(x$mpg, x$disp, data = x)))

statistic parameter p.value     estimate   null.value alternative method                                 data.name          conf.int 
4 -4.074021 9         0.002782827 -0.8052361 0          "two.sided" "Pearson's product-moment correlation" "x$mpg and x$disp" Numeric,2
6 0.2317344 5         0.8259297   0.1030827  0          "two.sided" "Pearson's product-moment correlation" "x$mpg and x$disp" Numeric,2
8 -2.107584 12        0.05677488  -0.519767  0          "two.sided" "Pearson's product-moment correlation" "x$mpg and x$disp" Numeric,2
```